# How to open external music players (such as Pulsar, Retro Music Players) and play a song which i have selected from my listview?

Tags: android, listview, audio, onclicklistener

I have list of songs from internal storage in listview, now onItemClickListener i added following code :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(parent.getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file), "audio/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    try {
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Music player not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It just opens Music Player, doesnt play the selected item(song).
Now, what do i have to do to play song?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found my mistake,

i had to use

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
```

instead of

```
intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(parent.getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file), "audio/*");
```

because 'Fileprovider' is only used to install apk from your app.